# Fourier Transform of Dyson's Equation

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, convolution, greens-function

I'm attempting to show that the Fourier transform of Dyson's equation for a constant potential V, 
\begin{equation}
    G(\mathbf{r},t,\mathbf{r}_0,t_0) 
        = 
            G^0(\mathbf{r},t,\mathbf{r}_0,t_0) + \dfrac{1}{\hbar} \int G^0(\mathbf{r},t,\mathbf{r}',t') VG(\mathbf{r}',t',\mathbf{r}_0,t_0) d^3 \mathbf{r}'d t'
\end{equation}
is
\begin{equation}
    G(\mathbf{k},\omega)
        = 
            G^0 (\mathbf{k},\omega) + \hbar^{-1} G^0 (\mathbf{k},\omega) V G(\mathbf{k},\omega)
\end{equation}

I'm having a bit of trouble showing the convolution portion of this, and could use a hand with the integration. My work is the following:

Since we are dealing with a constant potential, $ V(\mathbf{r}',t') = V $ and $G(\mathbf{r},t,\mathbf{r}_0,t_0) \rightarrow G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0) $. Applying the Fourier transform of both sides, we have 
\begin{align}
    \mathcal{F} \big \{ G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0)  \big \}
        &=
            \int G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0) e^{i\omega t - i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} d^3 \mathbf{r} d t
        \nonumber
        =
            G(\mathbf{k},\omega)
        \nonumber
        \\[.5em]
        &=
            \int \bigg [ G^0(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0) + \dfrac{1}{\hbar} \int G^0(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}',t-t') VG(\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{r}_0,t'-t_0) d^3 \mathbf{r}'d t' \bigg ] e^{i\omega t - i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} d^3 \mathbf{r} d t
        \nonumber
        \\[.5em]
        &=
            G^0(\mathbf{k},\omega) + \dfrac{V}{\hbar} \int \int G^0(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}',t-t') G(\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{r}_0,t'-t_0) d^3 \mathbf{r}'d t' e^{i\omega t - i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} d^3 \mathbf{r} d t
        \label{FT_ConstantV}
\end{align}

From here, I need to show that 
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{V}{\hbar} \int \int G^0(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}',t-t') G(\mathbf{r}'-\mathbf{r}_0,t'-t_0) e^{i\omega t - i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} 
 d^3 \mathbf{r}'d t' d^3 \mathbf{r} d t
=
\dfrac{V}{\hbar} G^0 (\mathbf{k},\omega)  G(\mathbf{k},\omega)
\end{equation}

I know this involves a convolution, but I am unsure how to show this. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit: Because this is a constant potential, $G(\mathbf{r},t,\mathbf{r}_0,t_0) \rightarrow G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0) $. I have edited my original work to reflect this.

Edit: $G^0 (\mathbf{k},\omega)$ and $G(\mathbf{k},\omega)$ represent the Fourier transform of $G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0)$ and $G^0(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0)$, respectively.

Comment: You need to define $G(k,\omega),G^0(k,\omega)$

Comment: @reuns , here they represent the FT of $G(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0,t-t_0)$. I will edit my post to reflect this.